# Python HTML getting div ID by text

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a bit of an unusual request; I want to get the id of a div based on the text it shows up on the webpage as. For example, say I have the following html:

```
<div class="productTabRightCompatibility">
 <h2>
  Product Downloads
 </h2>
 <ul class="listColumn">
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_0">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_one_technical_drawing" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_0" target="_blank">
    ProductOne Technical Drawing
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_1">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_two_cad_drawing" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_1" target="_blank">
    ProductOne CAD Drawing
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_2">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_three_installation_manual" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_2" target="_blank">
    ProductOne Installation Manual
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the website does not always have these in the same order, so sometimes the Technical Drawing is represented by the id ResourceLink_0, and sometimes the CAD drawing is. The only constant is that the item I want is represented with the text "[Product #] Technical Drawing". I want to be able to go through multiple pages and get the link that corresponds to the technical drawing regardless of order. At the moment I'm iterating through all of the links and looking for the one that contains "technical_drawing" somewhere in the link address, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to get to the result.

Comment: How do you want to improve over your previous solution? It seems to do what you want.

Comment: @Mr.Yellow I'm just wondering if there's a way to find a link based on the text it shows on the page rather than iterating through all links. If the way I'm doing it is the most efficient way, that's fine, just trying to make sure I keep things as pythonic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup` and `re` packages, you should be able to do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<div class="productTabRightCompatibility">
 <h2>
  Product Downloads
 </h2>
 <ul class="listColumn">
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_0">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_one_technical_drawing" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_0" target="_blank">
    ProductOne Technical Drawing
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_1">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_two_cad_drawing" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_1" target="_blank">ProductOne CAD Drawing</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_2">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_three_installation_manual" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_2" target="_blank">
    ProductOne Installation Manual
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
a_link = soup.find('a', text=re.compile("ProductOne Technical Drawing"))
print(a_link.get('href'))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
/-/dummy_link_one_technical_drawing
```

Comment: Why did you copied my answer?

Comment: 1. Please note that my edit has been wrote one minute before your answer
2. Be sure that I have a lot a things to do before "copying SO answers"
You are welcome

Comment: I saw what you have posted earlier.Ok.Dnt be over smart.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re` you can search the text of tag and then get the `href` value of that tag.
I have used `find_all` here in case if you have more than one element present on the page.

```
import bs4
import re
html_doc='''<html><div class="productTabRightCompatibility">
 <h2>
  Product Downloads
 </h2>
 <ul class="listColumn">
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_0">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_one_technical_drawing" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_0" target="_blank">
    ProductOne Technical Drawing
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_1">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_two_cad_drawing" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_1" target="_blank">
    ProductOne CAD Drawing
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_2">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_three_installation_manual" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_2" target="_blank">
    ProductOne Installation Manual
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div></html>'''

soup =bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
items=soup.find_all('a' , text=re.compile("Technical Drawing"))
for item in items:
  print(item['href'])
```

Output:

```
/-/dummy_link_one_technical_drawing
```

Comment: Right answer, just got Maaz's first.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid using find and regex and use a faster css attribute = value selector with ends with $ operator

```
[href$='technical_drawing']
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html='''<html><div class="productTabRightCompatibility">
 <h2>
  Product Downloads
 </h2>
 <ul class="listColumn">
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_0">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_one_technical_drawing" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_0" target="_blank">
    ProductOne Technical Drawing
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_1">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_two_cad_drawing" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_1" target="_blank">
    ProductOne CAD Drawing
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <div class="iconSprite icon16 iconDownloads" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_divResourceImage_2">
   </div>
   <a href="/-/dummy_link_three_installation_manual" id="layoutmain_1_ProductTabs1_rptResources_hlResourceLink_2" target="_blank">
    ProductOne Installation Manual
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div></html>'''

soup =bs(html, 'lxml')
link =soup.select_one("[href$='technical_drawing']")['href']
print(link)
```